# Run app on device starts with no default settings and params

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I'm testing my app and it all works fine in different emulators, but when I connect my Galaxy A50, it doesn't install fresh version of app.

My app has 2 `ArrayLists` that are empty on first install and some default settings in `SettingsActivity`. When I uninstall the app from my A50, and then "run app" from android studio, on same A50, `ArrayLists` are no longer empty, they contain some dummy objects I created days before and also settings are no longer set on default, they are changed like I set them. But that shouldn't be happening, I should get fresh empty default version of that app.

Is there some cache I need to clean???

EDIT: I just installed new AS 3.5 and I still have the problem only now I get different dataset, the same dataset as I had on the phone before I uninstalled my app and build it again from AS

Comment: you have to check your code. the issue isnt with the device, or android studio, its your code.

Comment: I don't think so. My code worked fine, and after couple of days this happend. Even when I build the same code and upload it to test track on google play, and then install it on my A50 - it works fine!!! But if I build it directly via usb cable to my A50 it loads with !default data set

Answer (score 0):

From [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/mobile-devices/galaxy-a50-clear-the-app-cache-and-data/)

> From Settings, swipe to and touch Apps. Swipe to and touch the app you
>   want to clear. Touch Storage, and then touch Clear cache.

Comment: Nope, tried all that, its not on my phone, the fault is at the android studio

Comment: When I download the unchanged version of my app from google play it works fine, but when I build it from AS then I get !default data set. NOTE: each time I uninstall app completely before install/build

Comment: @Nemanja This cannot be answered then without you posting your code

Comment: @Greatwon I have over 2k lines of code. I didn't change the code from the last time it was working properly. It somehow remembered my last session and keeps giving me that data set. When I build it and then install from .apk, all works fine and I get clean data. Is there any way to reset AS connection to my phone!?!?!?